# What connection string do I use for pyvisa when my TCP device is connected via a USB to Ethernet Adapter?

Tags: python, visa, pyvisa

I am attempting to communicate with a BraggMETER Interrogator that supports SCPI.

OS: Windows 10

Connection hardware: j5create JUH470 USB 3.0 Multi-Adapter Gigabit Ethernet / 3-Port USB 3.0 HUB

Part of my confusion: Should I access as a USB device or as a TCPIP device?

When I connect via Telnet, all goes well. The IP Address and Port are 10.0.0.10 and 3500.

```
> telnet
> open 10.0.0.10 3500
:IDEN?
:ACK:HBM FiberSensing:FS22SI v3.0:08:046 840 200 898:20190116
:STAT?
:ACK:1
```

In Python, I am usig the pyvisa library.

```py
import easy_scpi as scpi
import pyvisa

DeviceAddress = '10.0.0.10'
DevicePort = '3500'
VISADevice = f'TCPIP0::{DeviceAddress}::{DevicePort}::SOCKET'
# Doesn't work either --> VISADevice = 'ASRL10::INSTR'

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.list_resources())

inst = rm.open_resource(VISADevice)
print(inst.query("*IDEN?"))
inst.close()
```

The error is always on `rm.open_resource`. I have tried numerous connection strings. They give different errors. Here are three of them:

```
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_INTF_NUM_NCONFIG (-1073807195): The interface type is valid but the specified interface number is not configured.

pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.

pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.
```

**Update 1**

I downloaded National Instruments NI-Max and used their NI I/O trace. This  connection string "works":

```
TCPIP::10.0.0.10::3500::SOCKET
```

However, I still get the timeout error. Tried ensuring that the newline termination character is sent and upped the timeout to 5 seconds (which did take effect, as it delayed the logging of the timeout error). No dice. Still gives a timeout error.

**Update 2**

While not the same setup, someone else reports a problem who is using an NI GPIB-to-USB card (GPIB-USB-HS). The common thread is a USB adapter...

https://community.keysight.com/thread/37567

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not able to comment so I'm commenting here*

Have you tried using a normal socket?

```
import socket

DeviceAddress = '10.0.0.10'
DevicePort = '3500'
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (DeviceAddress, DevicePort)
cmd = "IDN?" # or "*IDEN?" as you've put?

braggMeterSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
braggMeterSocket.connect(self.ADDR)
braggMeterSocket.send(cmd + "\n") #maybe with new line depending on what the device terminator is.
mesg = braggMeterSocket.recv(BUFSIZ)
mesg = mesg.strip() # Remove \n at end of mesg
print(mesg)
```

Comment: That is what I am going to try next. Since Telnet works but all fancy tools (including National Instruments NI-Max) fail, it may be my only option. And yes - my device uses :IDEN? instead of :IDN? for some reason.

Comment: If you're able to get the device to work on telnet then I don't think it's the adapter. If you send it a command does it make the change? If that's the case, and it's just not able to send back data then I think the device is not terminating the command and thinks it hasn't finished; hence the timeout, it's waiting for more commands to be sent. Do you have a link to the manual? what are the instructions for the line termination?

Comment: I found the cause - my device expected carriage return linefeed as command delimiter but Python "\n" only sends one of those two characters.

Comment: Nice work. I've only used carriage return on older devices, interesting that some are still using it.

Comment: NI-Max only allows you to specify an optional single command termination character, typically newline or null character. That steered me wrong, making me think devices never had more than one character terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the device exects CRLF (carriage return plus linefeed) as an SCPI command terminator. I was only sending one of those two characters, "\n".

Python I/O does not adapt to the OS like some languages I have used, which will interpret "\n" as "\r\n" in some situations.

Likewise, NI-Max only sent the "\n" and omitted the "\r".